# Swift Getting Exact Conversion String to Float with floatValue

Tags: ios, swift, precision

I try to convert my string data to float type. Conversion works but I need exact value.

Here is my code and output;

```
let myString = "2558.40";
let convertedToFloat = (myString as NSString).floatValue

// convertedToFloat is 2558.3999
```

So, I need exactly `2558.40` as float type. What should I do?

Comment: Maybe? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Anyway, don't use `NSString`, use native Swift type `String` (so you don't have to convert it) and then just convert your string to `Float`: `let convertedToFloat = Float(myString)!` (or you can choose some safer method of optional unwrapping)

Comment: @RobertDresler Float(myString)! is still "2558.3999"

Comment: I didn't say that this would solve your problem, this is just an advice.

Comment: Floating point representation on 32 or 64 bits  (or even more bits) can't express all decimal number.You could try `let formatter = NumberFormatter(); let n = formatter.number(from: myString)!`

Comment: @Carpsen90 I get this: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

Comment: @FatihTAN I used forced unwrapping (`!`) for brevity, you should make sure that the string can be converted to a number with optional binding or guard

Comment: @Carpsen90 formatter.number(from: "2558.40") gives me nil. Are you sure, number() function returns float type.

Comment: @FatihTAN No it return an NSNumber

Comment: It's the answer pointed out by @RobertDresler states, it's not possible to exact represent that number. However, you might want to look into using `Double` or `Decimal`. For instance:
`let convertedToDouble = Double(myString)!`
`let convertedToDecimal = Decimal(myString)!`